# Is it okay to use steel strings on a nylon guitar?

Tags: guitar, strings

I replaced one nylon string (the G string) with a steel string. All the other strings are nylon. Is this okay?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is no. The tension of steel strings are way to much for a classical guitar to handle as it generally does not have a truss rod in the neck.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably get away with it on a temporary basis, but the tension isn't good for that guitar. Certainly, on a classical guitar, I wouldn't be putting all 6 on. One won't be too detrimental, but also the feel will be different - tighter, thinner - and certainly the sound will be different, so it's inappropriate for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Steel strings are available in a wide range of gauges, which will need different levels of tension to play at any given pitch.  For the most part, one may reduce the tension required to play a certain pitch by using a narrower string, but as metal strings get too loose, pitch stability suffers severely--much more so than with nylon strings.

The tension on a 13-gauge steel string (the "e'" from an heavy-gauge set or a "b" from a lighter set) would be about 9.7lbs.  That's rather light as steel strings go, but probably not unplayable, and it should be safe on a nylon-string guitar (many nylon sets average slightly over 10lbs).  I would not expect such a string to sound very good or offer a good playing experience when used in that fashion, but the tension should be low enough to avoid damaging anything.  Using a 14 gauge string would increase tension to about 11.2lbs; that would probably improve playability, and would probably be safe, but would leave less safety margin against accidental over-tightening.

Comment: I've used .008" top, .010" second for the last 40+yrs, with no pitch problems

Comment: @Tim: A 13ga "g" string would fit right in with a set of 8's for an electric.  Some people like 8's, and on a guitar with a suitable action height they can work just fine.  Nylon guitars often have higher actions, however, and I would expect that a 13ga "g" would be right on the cusp of usability--much better than a 12ga, but noticeably worse than a 14ga.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing one string with a steel one won't damage the guitar, but the playability of the guitar won't be good. Drive down to a local guitar store and buy a nylon replacement (or even a new full set).

Answer (score 0):

([I'm sure I answered this before...](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11809/putting-steel-strings-on-a-cheap-nylon-guitar/11811#11811))

Hey, it's *your* instrument; the guitar police won't break down your door for putting that string on your instrument. And it isn't like diesel in a gas engine; the damage won't be immediate and cause complete failure. The instrument will be playable until it won't.

But that's not what it's built for, and strings are cheap.