# Installing Ball-End Nylon Strings on a Classical Guitar

Tags: strings, classical-guitar

I'm looking to install ball-end nylon strings on a classical guitar.

Which of these ways is the best in terms of tone and preserving the bridge?

- The same way you install ball-end steel strings on a guitar: ball rests on the bridge hole, farthest from the nut.
- Loop the string around the bridge and then pass the string through the hole in the ball-end so that the ball end is on the opposite side of the bridge, closest to the nut. See photo. Note the extra ivory to preserve the corners. It's just wood on the bridge furthest from the nut.

I'd prefer not to discuss looping and knotting a string. Let's stick to ball-end strings. Thanks![image]

Comment: Why not cut the ball end of you believe that's the way to better tone? Or buy traditional strings? IIRC the balls are nylon or plastic, so they shouldn't do any damage (I wouldn't think) to a wooden bridge, but if you're previously inclined against them, why even bother?

Comment: @DaveJacoby it seems the OP precisely wanted to _avoid opions of people previously inclined against ball-ends_. I.e., not get into discussions about ball vs no-ball, but take the balls as a given and only discuss what to do with them.

Comment: @DaveJacoby I don't believe that ball-less strings give better tone. I was trying to avoid this exact comment thread.

Comment: Uuuh... that in your image is a _steel_ string though, isn't it? Never install (normal-tension) steel strings on a classical guitar, unless you want to destroy it!

Comment: @leftaroundabout let’s hope it was just laid on there loosely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was given this guitar and have just got the replacement strings. Sadly that string has been on for years in a closet.  Steel string is coming off forthwith!

Comment: Votes to close are because...?

Comment: There is no reason I can think of to loop the string through the ball-end. It's there to provide a mass that won't go through the hole at the back of the bridge.

Comment: There exist ball-end classical strings. I think the ones I had in years ago had a plastic ball-end, not steel. Strings are cheap; buy new strings that are appropriate for your instrument. Tying to bridge is traditional for classical guitar, but you do you. You don't need to loop ball-end strings. And, as always, _never_ put steel strings classical guitars. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11809/putting-steel-strings-on-a-cheap-nylon-guitar

Comment: My vtc was because it seems like a pointless question (to me), and needs more clarity. Buy a different set of strings, and compare the two.

Comment: @tim interesting that you chose to answer the question then.

Comment: With my bit of experience, just trying to be helpful..! No-one else seems to be helpful.

Comment: @tim it's not about different sets of strings it's about how to set a particular kind of string namely ball end strings.

Answer (score 3):

Tone wise, there's very very little, or no difference. The string doesn't vibrate past the saddle, so what you do will make no difference.

Thread the string through the hole, over the saddle, then as normal.

As a pro muso, I'd try both ways - as explained, and wrapping, and record the two, but I wouldn't waste my time. There's probably more tonal difference to be found in different *makes* of strings rather than using ball-ends. I'm not sure what the point is.

Comment: I agree, bridge to nut is where the sound is and what counts. I wouldn’t even bother doing an A/B. If anything having the ball end on the saddle side might make indentations on top of the bridge since the ball might ride up with the tension so I would just go traditional.